# How do I display PHP code in HTML?

Tags: php, html

How do I display PHP code in HTML?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
highlight_file('myFile.php');
```

or change the file extension to phps

Comment: @delive - of course, just specify whatever filename you want; set it to a variable, whatever

Comment: this method not is ilegal ?

Comment: @delive -  No, it is not illegal.... you will not be arrested for writing a script that displays the source code of your files

Comment: @MarkBaker the PHPolice may be watching you though ;) Btw, the companion function [`highlight_string($str)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php) **reads directly from a string** instead of a file. In both the second parameter when set to `TRUE` will return the generated HTML code instead of outputting it like `echo`.

Answer (score 21):

Just like any other piece of text:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$code = '<?php
echo "Hello, World!";
?>';

echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($code) . '</pre>';

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Optionally, PHP has a [builtin function to generate syntax highlight](http://php.net/highlight_string):

```
<?php

$code = '<?php
echo "Hello, World!";
?>';

highlight_string($code);

?>
```

Comment: If the file extension is HTML then can we use PHP code?

Answer (score 7):

Replace all occurences of `<` with `&lt;` (and optionally `>` with `&gt;`):

```
<pre>
&lt;?php echo 'hello world'; ?&gt;
</pre>
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use the `<pre>` tag:

```
<pre>SOME HTML ENCODED PHP CODE</pre>
```

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how to properly display PHP code, simply wrapping it in `<pre>` tags won't stop it from actually running if it's being included in a `.php` file for example. It needs to be properly escaped prior to wrapping it in `<pre>`