# Prevent php from rendering/executing between pre tags

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, rendering

I'm using pre tags to display codesnippets on my website, these snippets contain html and php.

So far I've used Jquery to convert html in the codesnippets to plain text, but the php tags are still being executed.

The code that I used for converting the html contents of the pre tag to plain text:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("pre").text($("pre").html()); 
});
```

An example of what I'm using it on:

```
<pre>
    <p>paragraph Content</p>
    <h1>html code</h1>
    <?php echo "this is php example code"; ?>
</pre>
```

The first 2 lines display in the browser with the tags and everything perfectly, but the third line execute the php tags rendering only **this php example code**. Can anyone help me out so I can display the php tags in my code snippet aswell?

Also if anybody knows a better solution to rendering html/css and php as a code snippet on your website It would be really helpfull.

Comment: Ideally you could set up something like  syntaxhighlighter (http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) which gives the user more than just a row and you don't have to do any formatting by yourself.

Comment: Planning on using it, but still doesn't take away the fact that when I input php tag inside of the pre tags of that SyntaxHighlighter it's being run instead of displayed as plain text.

Comment: Well if you're planning to display code it's quite redundant to have the opening and close-tags for php, especially if its just snippets... If you really want to keep them several ppl has already provided the answer =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display PHP code in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842575/how-do-i-display-php-code-in-html)

Comment: Not totally because I get how to display PHP code in HTML but I want to get it done automatically to the contents of a pre tag anywhere on my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is, that you try to influence the rendering after the browser has processed the file. When you look at the sourcecode of your page, you will notice that there really is nothing else than "this php example code" in there, because the server parsed that part of your code and executed it, which leads to nothing but the string you put into that `echo` command.

You need to handle your output before your send it to the client and fetch all occurrences of `<pre>` and `</pre>` to replace all `<` and `>` between them with their respective HTML entities.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php) to find out the best approach to parse the HTML and get the appropriate elements in order to modify them.

Comment: This looks like one of the better answers and It's also what I've already been afraid of. This goes alot deeper than my current knowledge since I hardly know anything about parsing html. 

The endgoal having similar snippets as on net.tutplus.com, should be an easier way to go about all of this.

Comment: The easiest solution probably would be to put the code snippet into a variable (maybe by reading it from a file) and then run that through `htmlspecialchars()` before you output it. This would work easily, realiably and without HTML parsing. If you want or need to embed the snippets into the page without extracting them into separate files, HTML parsing will probably be your only option.

Answer (score 2):

You should escape the `<` and `>` symbols - replace them with their HTML entities, `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively ;)

If you want a total and comprehensive conversion to HTML entities, try converting them over at http://centricle.com/tools/html-entities

Generally it's good practice to convert all symbols to their respective HTML entities within a code block.

Comment: No need for a separate tool to convert HTML entities, you can just echo the result of PHP's `htmlentities` instead.

Comment: Yep, that, too. Forgot that the OP is running a PHP script at the first place ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `<?php ... ?>` with

`&lt;? .... &gt;`

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre>
    &lt;p&gt;paragraph Content&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;h1&gt;html code&lt;/h1&gt;
    &lt;?php echo "this is php example code"; ?&gt;
</pre>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pRVGH/) so you can see how it renders on the page.

Comment: As you're using PHP you could always pass it through PHP's `htmlentities` function. This will encode the input as above. Placing `<?php ... ?>` on a PHP page will see PHP rendering the content *before* the JavaScript is executed. Also, using JavaScript to encode the HTML would be a bad idea as those with JavaScript disabled will end up seeing a really messy website.

Comment: Thanks, haven't really thought about that, I'm looking for a way to automatically do this whenever I have a pre tag though. I don't wanna write out the htmlentities function everytime and input the data from the pre though in it.

Comment: You say you want it automated but it sounds like you're putting the content in manually anyway. If you are doing this manually, just do a simple find and replace to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. If the content is being added to the page automatically (from a database or external file), simply pass the content through the `htmlentities` function before displaying it on the page.

Comment: I'm adding the code snippet content manually that's correct but I don't wanna write out the functions surrounding the content everytime. Since it's mostly copy paste from my code editor.

Comment: In that case just use find and replace. Most popular text editors support this - simply paste in your code, find and replace, copy the changed code and put it on your site. Shouldn't take longer than 20 seconds, and won't waste resources having your server or users browsers doing the replacement for you.