# How to achieve downloading file as well as updating database in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have a file that is downloaded though my site. I want to count the number of downloads.  I have achieved it with the following code:

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db("a7871565_first",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");
$result = mysql_query("select * from downloads");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$count= $row{'download'};
$count= $count+1;
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE downloads SET download =$count");
echo "<script>";

    $url = "http://www.mohammediatechnologies.in/apps/TubeMateHd.apk";
    echo "window.open('$url');".PHP_EOL;

echo "</script>";
```

It does update the database with count as well as downloads the file but when the user clicks on the download button he is redirected to the file named download.php containing the code above. The user is presented with a blank screen which is something I don't want. The file download is opening in another window that is blocked as it is considered as a popup.

What I want to achieve is when the user clicks on the download link, the user stays on the same page, the database updates and the file is downloaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882472/php-send-file-to-user - look into this, it will tell you how to make a php script that will send the file but not refresh the page for the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I display PHP code in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842575/how-do-i-display-php-code-in-html)

Comment: @bub - Nope, but the question title is pretty fun, right? Can you imagine?

Comment: Please paste in some code samples

Comment: @musa check tubemate.gq and press download 1. its taking me to blank page 2. download is blocked by popup of browser my goal is to stay in same page initiate download and also execute php code in download.php file

Comment: So, If I am correct, you want to make the user download, it does not matter JS or PHP, also you want download.php to execute at the time of download. So I think this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php

Comment: @musa it helped me and its working how do i accept your comment as answer here

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments too, you want to make the user download, it does not matter JS or PHP, also you want download.php to execute at the time of download. So I think this may help you: [How to force file download with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263923/how-to-force-file-download-with-php)

Basically when you want to **force download** a file in a browser, you need to set proper headers to the browser, so it knows you want the user to download the file, and then send the data to the browser.

In PHP frameworks there are some helper function to help you do the same (eg. in *codeigniter* you can use `force_download()` to achieve the same task).