# Display code snippet in Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

i need to display as text on the screen a snippet that contains some php variables, but when i load the page Laravel resolve this variables and give me a undefined variable error. Basically i need that when i try to display the snippet inside `<code></code>` tags it print something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript>
    var variable = '<?= $variable ?>';
</script>
```

I have tried already with {{htmlspecialchars}} but not work

Comment: What way are you trying to display this, can you give the chunk of code that you are using?

Comment: <code class="break-word">{{htmlspecialchars($code) }}</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can assign the code to a variable :

```
$var = Blade::compileString('<script type=\'text/javascript\'>
    var variable = \'<?= $variable ?>\';
</script>');
```

In your blade, access the variable as :

```
{{ $var }}
```

Comment: Another brick on my wall. Many thks. Very usefull

Answer (score 1):

You can use `highlight_string($code)` to show the snippet. Inspiration from this post: [How do I display PHP code in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842575/how-do-i-display-php-code-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to enclose your snippet on a `@verbatim` block. This should escape its content of the rendering.

See more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data